# Why doesn't one get an error that the command is already defined?

Tags: unicode-math

If I compile

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \newcommand*\Nu{\mathit{Nu}}
%    \newcommand*\Nu{bla}
\begin{document}
    $\Nu$
\end{document}
```

(with LuaLaTeX) with an up-to-date MiKTeX this results in

[image: image showing the result of above code with is an upright capital N]

rather than in an italic "Nu". That seems because `unicode-math` seems to define that command which can be verified by commenting the currently not commented `\newcommand` line.

But then I would guess/hope to get the error message

> `! LaTeX Error: Command \Nu already defined.`
>               `Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

as one gets if you uncomment the currently commented `\newcommand` line.

Does anybody have a clue why this is so and/or if this is a bug in `unicode-math`? Or does anybody have an idea how I can preserve the original command and still make the new one effective instead of renaming it?

Comment: The reason for why no error is reported has been given, but I would like to point out that it's been traditional in math publications for hundreds of years to print uppercase greek upright.  The reason is that printers usually didn't have italic uppercase greek metal type.  Be that as it may, tradition is tradition, and math publishers honor tradition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unicode-math` (unfortunately) does almost all its definitions `\AtBeginDocument` so the command is not defined at that point.
(so you can place a redefinition after `\begin{document}` or in `\AtBeginDocument`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So I guess `unicode-math` is then using `\providecommand` to define it and that is the reason why I don't get any hint in the LOG, right? Is that intended behavior, i.e. a feature or a bug? In my point of view this is a bug because it took me quite some time to find that difference after I added that package to a books preamble with more than 450 pages ... Would there be any negative consequences/drawbacks if I would define that command via `\AtBeginDocument` and thus override `unicode-math`s command?

Comment: @StefanPinnow not providecommand that would not define most things it uses \def or \mathchardef etc as by design it is over-writing existing math definitions from the format or amssymb etc to fit the unicode locations so it is _expecting_ to redefine thousands of commands so doesn't warn about each one.

Comment: no you can certainly redefine that. also see https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/548

Comment: You say, “unfortunately,” but this allows it to work with the many, many classes and templates that load a Type 1 font, regardless of loading order. It’s not the most intuitive design feature, but it’s saved me a lot of problems over the years.

Comment: @Davislor sure but there would be other ways to do that and it comes at a heavy price in terms of making it difficult (or at least confusing) to customise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fair enough. Your answer, you’re entitled to share your opinion.